# Running Macroplant iExplorer on my Windows computer, and my iPhone isn't showing. But it shows in windows explorer

Tags: mac, iphone

Running Macroplant iExplorer https://macroplant.com/iexplorer on my Windows computer, and my iPhone isn't showing. But it shows in windows explorer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

macroplant iexplorer requires installing iTunes is a pre-requisite.

there's also a program called Tenoshare iCareFone, that also requires iTunes as a pre-requisite.

Once iTunes is installed them those programs should be able to see the iPhone.